# Error in react-native-i18n while generate apk from react-native in Jenkins

Tags: android, jenkins, internationalization, react-native

I have the error:

```
:react-native-i18n:processReleaseResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-i18n:processReleaseResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
```

When I want to generate my application from react-native use my Jenkinsfile script.

```
dir('src/Mobile/android'){
sh 'chmod +x ./gradlew'
sh 'ANDROID_HOME=/home/user/android ./gradlew assembleDefault'
archive '*/build/outputs/apk/*.apk'
```

I can run the application in the local environment but my server with Jenkins can't build my App. Any idea how to solve this problem?